# Limit custom MSBuild target to the file(s) selected in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, target

I have a small custom MSBuild target:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Foo Include="file1.foo"/>
   <Foo Include="file2.foo"/>
   <Foo Include="file3.foo"/>
   ...
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Foo2Bar" Inputs="foo.config;@(Foo)" Outputs="%(Foo.Filename).bar">
   <Exec Command="path\to\script @(Foo) -o %(Foo.Filename).bar"/>
</Target>
```

Now I want to be able to to select one of the `*.foo`-files in Visual Studio and trigger processing just this one (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> or right clicking in the Solution Explorer -> *Compile*). It seems that this sets a property `$(SelectedFiles)`, but I don't find any usable tutorial or example how to make this work...

Answer (score 0):

> Limit custom MSBuild target to the file(s) selected in Visual Studio

If I understand you correctly, you want to select one of `*.foo` file to the target, if yes, you can pass the list around as a property, so we need to convert item into a property:

```
<Target Name="BuildMigrationZip">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <FooProperty>@(Foo)</FooProperty>
   </PropertyGroup>

  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="Foo2Bar"
           Properties="FilesToFoo=$(FooProperty)" />
</Target>
```

Then when we build the this file with MSBuild command line, we could pass the property `FooProperty`:

```
msbuild.exe "YourCustomTargetFile" /p:FooProperty=file1.foo
```

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587436/pass-list-item-to-properties-when-calling-reusable-msbuild-target) for some more details info.

If I understand you incorrect, please let me know for free, I will keep follow ASAP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only lets me select files on the command line, right?. I want to select the files in the Visual Studio IDE. It already works that with F7 all out-of-date files are processed. I now want to trigger processing selected files with Ctrl-F7 (no matter if out-of-date or not, just like with the built-in `ClCompile` target)

Comment: @Tobi, Yes, this only let you select file on the command line. If you want to select the file in the Visual Studio IDE, we have to over write the Ctrl-F7 with your custom target. Or you can develop a item extension like Ctrl-F8 to invoke your custom target. These two methods are not simple. You can check this thread for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835043/how-to-override-compile-command-of-visual-studio-2017-community

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies @Leo! Somehow this seems way too complicated for such a simple thing. For comparison: In Xcode, my desired behavior is the default. Cmd-B executes all build rules Ctrl-Cmd-B just the one for the selected file, not matter if it's a built-in or custom processing rule. And I still believe it's somehow possible in MSBuild, as it works for the built-in targets: If a `*.cpp` file is selected, only `ClCompile` is executed (and only on this file), if an `*.idl` is selected, only  the `Midl` target (also only on the selected file)...