# Calling subtarget twice results in this target being skipped. How to prevent?

Tags: msbuild

I am using `MSBuild` to run some management scripts, so no compiler or linker is involved here and I noticed that the build system skips target which ran successfully in a target.

How do I force to run a target every time?

Sample:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Foo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="Foo" >
        <CallTarget Targets="Bar" />
        <CallTarget Targets="Bar" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Bar" >
         <Message Text="Bar" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Calling

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe msbuild.xml /v:d
```

Results in

```
Bar:
  Bar
```

so it is not called twice, /v:d says that second call was skipped, but it is not clear how to avoid this without creating Targets `Bar1` and `Bar2`

Is there a way to execute target `Bar` two times in `Foo`?

Searching for that revolved around cl.exe, xcopy etc detecting no changes but this is `MSBuild` only

Comment: ok just figured this is a duplicate: [How to invoke the same msbuild target twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332731/how-to-invoke-the-same-msbuild-target-twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tagets are only called once in a build unless something changed, so if you want the same target to be invoked multiple times you have to trick MsBuild into this by altering properties. This can be done like this:

```
<Target Name="Foo" >
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MsBuildThisFile)" Targets="Bar" Properties="Dummy=1" />
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MsBuildThisFile)" Targets="Bar" Properties="Dummy=2" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Bar" >
  <Message Text="Bar" />
</Target>
```

However as the 'trick' indicates: there is almost always a more 'MsBuild' way of doing this (usually batching over an ItemGroup), so if you make your question more specicic there might be a better answer as well.